# What is the basic lemma on composition of probability generating functions?

Tags: probability-distributions, generating-functions

What is the basic lemma on composition of probability generating functions and how is it most clearly proved?

(I'm posting this mainly to see if I can write an answer as clearly and simply as possible, but maybe other people know things about this that I don't and can post answers from their points of view.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?  Let $S = \sum_{i\le N} Y_i$ where $N, Y_1, Y_2, \ldots$ are independent integer-valued random variables where $N\ge 0$ a.s., and $\mathbb E[z^N] = f(z)$ while $\mathbb E[z^{Y_i}] = g(z)$, then
$$ \mathbb E[z^S] = f(g(z))$$

Comment: That's it. I was wondering if (1) there was a clearer and simpler way to look at it or at its proof or at its uses than what I thought of after realizing that in a recent posting I managed to make it all more complicated than necessary because my attention was primarily on other aspects of my topic at that moment.

Comment: My next thought after posting this is the following: With the notation above, if $N\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda),$ then the cumulants of $S$ are $\lambda$ times the moments of $Y_1$ (so every moment sequence is also a cumulant sequence, although obviously not conversely). So can anything similar be said if we drop the assumption on the distribution of $N\text{?}$ Maybe that's just silly, or maybe not. I don't have any very immediate occasion to want an answer to that.

Comment: Haste makes waste: My item numbered (1) in a comment above was to be followed by an item numbers (2), and now I see that it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a random variable $X$ takes values in the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\},$ each finite cardinal number having a probability assigned to it, their sum being $1.$

The ordinary generating function of this sequence of probabilities is
$$
g_X(s) = \sum_{x=0}^\infty \Pr(X=x) s^x = \operatorname E(s^X).
$$
It is routine to see that if $X,Y$ are independent random variables then
\begin{align*}
& g_{X+Y}(s) = \operatorname E(s^{X+Y}) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname E(s^X) \operatorname E(s^Y) & & \text{by independence} \\[8pt]
= {} & g_X(s) g_Y(s).
\end{align*}
(This simplicity of this argument is something that I actually missed in a recent stackexchange posting because my attention at that moment was on other aspects of my topic.)

**Lemma:** Suppose $X$ is as above and $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,\ldots$ are identically distributed, also taking values in $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $X, Y_1,Y_2, Y_3,\ldots$ are independent. Let $g_Y$ denote the probability generating function of any of $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,\ldots\,.$ Let
$$
Z = \sum_{n=1}^X Y_n.
$$
Then $g_Z(s) = g_X(g_Y(s)).$

**Proof:**
\begin{align}
g_Z(s) & = \operatorname E(s^Z) = \operatorname E(\operatorname E(s^Z \mid X)) \\[8pt]
& = \operatorname E( \operatorname E(s^{Y_1+\cdots+Y_X} \mid X)) \\[8pt]
& = \operatorname E( g_Y(s)^X ) & &\text{(This follows from} \\
& & & \phantom{\text{(}}\text{the “routine'' thing} \\
& & & \phantom{\text{(}}\text{mentioned above.)} \\[8pt]
& = g_X(g_Y(s)).
\end{align}